# Compile-time and runtime casting c#

Tags: c#, .net, casting, type-systems

I was wondering why some casts in C# are checked at compile-time whereas in other cases the responsibility is dumped on CLR. Like above both are incorrect but handled in a different way.

```
class Base { }
class Derived : Base { }
class Other { }

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Derived d = (Derived)new Base();     //Runtime       InvalidCastException
    Derived d = (Derived)new Other();    //Compile-time  Cannot convert type...
}
```

While reading *"C# in depth"* I've found the information on this topic where autor says:
  *"If the compiler spots that it’s actually impossible for that cast to work, it’ll trigger a compilation error—and if it’s theoretically allowed but actually incorrect at execution time, the CLR will throw an exception."*

Does 'theoretically' mean connected by inheritance hierarchy (some another affinity between objects ?) or it is compiler's internal business?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

- Upcasts can be checked at compile time - the type system guarantees that the cast succeeds.
- Downcasts cannot (in general) be checked at compile time, so they are always checked at runtime.
- Unrelated types cannot be cast to each other.

The compiler considers only the static types. The runtime checks the dynamic (runtime) type.
Looking at your examples:

```
Other x = new Other();
Derived d = (Derived)x;
```

The static type of `x` is `Other`. This is unrelated to `Derived` so the cast fails at compile time.

```
Base x = new Base();
Derived d = (Derived)x;
```

The static type of `x` is now `Base`. Something of type `Base` *might* have dynamic type `Derived`, so this is a downcast. In general the compiler can't know from the static type of `x` if it the runtime type is `Base`, `Derived`, of some other subclass of `Base`. So the decision of whether the cast is allowed is left to the runtime.

Comment: So one can assume that the compiler also checks implicit/explicit cast operator overloads?

Answer (score 2):

If your variable is of `Base` type, is can be theoretically constructed by `Derived` constructor, thus being a variable of `Derived` type actually. At compile time, compiler does not bother itself with trying to figure out whether in each particular case such downcast (representing a variable of `Base` type as an entity of `Derived` type) is possible.

Your sample is simple - you create a new class and cast it right away. But what if you get `Base` from somewhere else, e.g., some method call? Compiler just cannot "guess" what your method is going to return and therefore throw on not throw an error.

When you cast `Other`, compiler sees that there is no possibility that `Other` is actually `Derived` and throws an exception.