# C#: Does typecasting of constants happen at runtime?

Tags: c#, casting, enums, runtime, compile-time

Firstly, this question is **not a duplicate** of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4499528/compile-time-and-runtime-casting-c-sharp). Other than the title it has absolutely nothing in common.

Now...

In C#, consider the following situations:

```
int i = (int)10.0;

const double D = 10.0;
float f = (float)d; 

enum Foo : int
{
    FIRST_ITEM = 0
}
int i = (int)Foo.FIRST_ITEM;
```

In which of these situations does the typecasting happen at runtime? I currently feel like obsessing over my program's performance a little, and was wondering whether this would have any (no matter how small) influence.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Compile-time and runtime casting c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4499528/compile-time-and-runtime-casting-c-sharp)

Comment: Premature micro-optimization is a root of all evil. Build a working app with clear architecture, run a profiler over it and optimize only the parts that are worth optimizing.

Comment: It's compile-time for constants. If you want to know for sure, use `Reflector` to inspect the output code.

Comment: Thanks, @MatthewWatson. To the people tagging this as a duplicate: Please check the contents of questions/answers too; not just the titles.

Comment: That does entirely depend on your compiler. What environment are you using and what compilation flags? In general most "casts" for compile time value-constants are done at statically. To those screaming duplicate, note that he asked when the actual cast is done, not when the check whether or not the actual cast is valid is done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In short, Linqpad does a lot statically, which means that when compiling with either the ms or mono compiler with optimization flags on they should at least not do less statically.

When using Linqpad I get with the following C# code:

```
void Main()
{
  int i = (int)10.0;

  const double D = 10.0;
  float f = (float)D; 

  int h = (int) Foo.Bar;
}

public enum Foo : int {
  Bar = 0
}
```

I get the following IL:

```
IL_0001:  ldc.i4.s    0A // load int8 0A (ie 10 dec)
IL_0003:  stloc.0     // assign i
IL_0004:  ldc.r4      00 00 20 41 // FLOAT! not double
IL_0009:  stloc.1     // assign f
IL_000A:  ldc.i4.0    // load int32 0 (due to Foo : int(32))
IL_000B:  stloc.2     // assign h
```

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, but does that mean that `Foo.Bar` gets cast at compile time too?

Comment: @ArnoSluismans Yes it does, because the compiler knows its static type and can therefore optimise away any checking.

Comment: @ArnoSluismans Yes. And he beat me to it again. Well played Mr Watson :)

Answer (score 2):

Casts from constants are done at compile time.

To prove this, you can use [.Net Reflector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Reflector) to inspect the generated code.

For example, this code:

```
static void Main()
{
    int i = (int) 10.5;
    const double d = 10.0;
    float f = (float)d;

    Console.WriteLine(i);
    Console.WriteLine(f);
}
```

Produces:

```
private static void Main()
{
    int i = 0xa;
    float f = 10f;
    Console.WriteLine(i);
    Console.WriteLine(f);
}
```

Or as IL:

```
.method private hidebysig static void Main() cil managed
{
    .entrypoint
    .maxstack 1
    .locals init (
        [0] int32 i,
        [1] float32 f)
    L_0000: ldc.i4.s 0xa
    L_0002: stloc.0 
    L_0003: ldc.r4 10
    L_0008: stloc.1 
    L_0009: ldloc.0 
    L_000a: call void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(int32)
    L_000f: ldloc.1 
    L_0010: call void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(float32)
    L_0015: ret 
}
```

As you can see, no runtime casts are happening. It's the same for release OR debug builds.

Comment: Darn, you beat me to it by like a second :)

Comment: Well if it's any consolation, that's what usually happens to me... ;)