# Conflict between typecasting

Tags: c#, casting

Why:

```
int x = 3;
string y = x.toString();
```

**^ works**

and

```
int x = 3;
string y = (string)x;
```

**^ doesnt works**

curiosity brings me here ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the first uses the method [`int.ToString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6t7dwaa5(v=vs.110).aspx) to **convert** an `int` to it's `string` representation  whereas the second tries to [cast](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173105.aspx) the `int` to `string` which doesn't work because it is actually  not a `string` but an `int`.

[Read](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173105.aspx):

> Explicit conversions (casts): Explicit conversions require a cast
>   operator. Casting is required when information might be lost in the
>   conversion, or when the conversion might not succeed for other
>   reasons.

`String` and `Int32` are not related at all, so they cannot be casted to each other and already the compiler will throw an error. Sometimes the compiler compiles successfully but you get an `InvalidCastException` at runtime when the cast failed.

Read: [Compile-time and runtime casting c#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4499528/284240)

Note that you can **convert** the `int` to `string` via `ToString` and you can **convert** a `string` to `int` via `int.Parse`(or `int.TryParse`):

```
int z = int.Parse("3");
```

Comment: Tim is right int  first code line `Int.tostring()` is method and in second code you are doing casting from Int **structure** to string **Class** which gives error.

Answer (score 0):

`ToString` isn't type casting. It's a method, inherited from `object` and implemented in `System.Int32`, which converts the integer to a string representation.

An int isn't a string, so casting rightfully fails. The  `ToString` method is where you put custom logic that typecasting doesn't have, for converting an instance to its string representation. You can (and often should) implement `ToString` yourself in your custom classes and structs - it's often useful to have a meaningful string representation.